# Ошибка Namespace '"vue/types/vue"' has no exported member 'ExtendedVue' при использование библиотеки vee-validate

Tags: vue.js, typescript, валидация

Использую в проекте библиотеку vee-validate для валидации формы. Возникла следующая проблема при запуске yarn start (см. ниже). Возможно пофиксить данную проблему без перехода на vue 3 и vee-validate 4?

Сборка

```
"vee-validate": "^3.4.4",
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"typescript": "^3.4.3"
```

Сообщение в терминале

```
ERROR in /front/node_modules/vee-validate/dist/types/components/Observer.d.ts
    19:66 Namespace '"vue/types/vue"' has no exported member 'ExtendedVue'.
       failed: boolean;
      
      export declare const ValidationObserver: import("vue/types/vue").ExtendedVue<Vue & {
                                                               ^
        $_veeObserver: VeeObserver;
         $vnode: VNodeWithVeeContext;
       }, {
    ERROR in /front/node_modules/vee-validate/dist/types/components/Provider.d.ts
    3:66 Namespace '"vue/types/vue"' has no exported member 'ExtendedVue'.
        import Vue from 'vue';
        import { ValidationFlags, ValidationResult, VeeObserver, VNodeWithVeeContext } from '../types';
      export declare const ValidationProvider: import("vue/types/vue").ExtendedVue<Vue & {
                                                                 ^
         $_veeObserver: VeeObserver;
        _needsValidation: boolean;
        _inputEventName: string;
    ERROR in /front/node_modules/vee-validate/dist/types/localeChanged.d.ts
    2:50 Namespace '"vue/types/vue"' has no exported member 'CombinedVueInstance'.
      import Vue from 'vue';
      declare const EVENT_BUS: import("vue/types/vue").CombinedVueInstance<Vue, object, object, object, Record<never, any>>;
                                                        ^
        export declare function localeChanged(): void;
        export { EVENT_BUS };
```

Comment: [Namespace '"vue/types/vue"' has no exported member 'ExtendedVue'](https://www.google.com/search?q=Namespace+%27%22vue%2Ftypes%2Fvue%22%27+has+no+exported+member+%27ExtendedVue%27&oq=Namespace+%27%22vue%2Ftypes%2Fvue%22%27+has+no+exported+member+%27ExtendedVue%27)

Comment: Спасибо, уже пройденный этап)

Comment: пожалуйста, если разобрались, закройте вопрос

Comment: С решением проблемы я пока еще не разобрался. То что Вы скинули я смотрел до того, как написать здесь.

Comment: @nörbörnën, выдачи гугла могут отличаться для разных людей

Comment: @qwabra а для одинаковых людей могут отличаться?

Comment: @qwabra ох, ничему этот гугл не учится...

Comment: @nörbörnën, ок. https://www.google.com/?q=pyramid (3) ссылка trypyramid.com (4) lectureswww.readthedocs.io/6.www.sync/3.framework/pyramid (6) docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest

Comment: @qwabra вот ты серьёзный :) выдача отличается от браузера к браузеру, но 7 ссылок на странице о нём. инкогнито тоже. upd: да, именно такие ссылки (но уже без проверки в инкогнито)

Comment: @qwabra стоп. а мы в города играем? тогда дрезден

Comment: @nörbörnën, :) для окончания опыта нам нужна "бухгалтерша Маша". Тоже подумал про инкогнито но глядя на рекламу гугла есть серьёзные подозрения что он понимает компьютеры в одной сети...

Comment: @qwabra не, чуви, Маша тут таки не нужна. мы с тобой подтвердили, что квабра == норборнен (наверняка мы имеем сходные сценарии ежедневного околопрограммистского гуглежа). так же, из 4того коммента, мы знаем, что Дип умеет гуглить, а из вопроса, что он - программист (хотя и фронт). значит норборнен == дип. давай лучше в города? :)

Comment: @nörbörnën, хмм, ок. нью дели